# Papers about raising awareness within a domain about open source technologies

Tags: publications

Part of my (computer science) research work involves a relatively new open source technology that I feel has been overlooked by the research community. It would seem valuable to raise the awareness of this technology to the research community in a few different subdomains of the field. Would a paper that describes the open source technology, explains how it works, *and demonstrates its utility with some original, albeit simple, work* be ethical? While I have contributed to the open source technology, I am by no means a primary creator, and would intend to include some of the main contributors and original creator as secondary authors.

The question [Should I write a paper on open-source software I've built?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19855/should-i-write-a-paper-on-open-source-software-ive-built?rq=1) is related, but this question is asking about open source software that I only contributed to, as one of hundreds of contributors.

Comment: Write a blog post.  Those get read more widely anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to get the ball rolling. 
I do not see any major problem if you:

- Significant contributed to the software;
- Enables new research challenges to be addressed or address research challenges significantly better (e.g., faster, easier, simpler).