# Citing contributors to open source project when publishing to Zenodo

Tags: software, open-access

[appleseed](https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed), our open source (MIT) physically-based rendering software, is used in various circles, one of them being academia.

We have been asked to obtain a DOI so that our software could be cited. We're planning to publish our releases to [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/).

GitHub currently lists 69 contributors on our main repository. Should we consider *all of them* as authors of the software, or would it be more appropriate to somehow select a subset of the contributors?

If the latter, how should we define such a subset? We have all kinds of contributors: one-time contributors, occasional contributors, regular contributors, core contributors, project owners, Google Summer of Code students, mentors... Who should we include or exclude?

**Edit 1:** here is a paper that seems relevant:

*Smith AM, Katz DS, Niemeyer KE, FORCE11 Software Citation Working Group. 2016. Software citation principles. PeerJ Computer Science 2:e86*
https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj-cs.86

**Edit 2:** here is a tentative publication of our latest official release to Zenodo:
https://zenodo.org/record/3384658

Comment: Are you planning on getting a DOI for every release? That's quite different from the usual approach I see for academic software, where one writes a [paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/19855/17254) announcing and describing the software, and only write a replacement paper in case of major updates.

Comment: @Anyon The standard process at Zenodo with the Github integration is to get a DOI pointing to the entire project (always referencing the latest release), and additionally a DOI for every release. This allows both abstract references to the entire project, and precise references to specific software versions. https://guides.github.com/activities/citable-code/

Comment: @malexmave Interesting! Thanks for the information.